# Removing data after the secod last forward slash in a string

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a folder location similar to `/home/uploads/images/img1.png/`.
I need to get the string after second last occurrence of `/`, here what I need is `/home/uploads/images/`.

How can I do this? Any help?

Comment: Try to use indexOf , set delimiter as slash

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use regex in [`replace()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) to removing extra characters.

```js
var path = "/home/uploads/images/img1.png/".replace(/[^\/]+\/$/g, "");
console.log(path);
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you want to extract `/home/uploads/images/` from your string `/home/uploads/images/img1.png/`

```
var str = "/home/uploads/images/img1.png/";
var extracted = str.substring(0,str.substring(0,str.lastIndexOf("/")-1).lastIndexOf("/")+1);
```

is one of the ways to do it. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

a little playing with your string as an array :)

```
var url = '/home/uploads/images/img1.png/';
url.split('/').reverse().slice(2,a.split('/').length).reverse().join('/')
```